# Magento 2 Error: Class does not exist

Tags: magento2, php

I see this error

> 3 exception(s): Exception #0
>   (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Invalid block type:
>   Crediya\Minicalculadora\Block\Data Exception #1 (ReflectionException):
>   Class CrediYa\CrediYa\Model\CrediYa does not exist Exception #2
>   (ReflectionException): Class CrediYa\CrediYa\Model\CrediYa does not
>   exist

But the class does exist, if I use the command

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

I get the following error

```
Fatal error: Class 'CrediYa\CrediYa\Model\CrediYa' not found in /var/www/html/magento2/generated/code/CrediYa/CrediYa/Model/CrediYa/Interceptor.php on line 7
```

How can I solve these errors?

Comment: did you get a solution? if not then show you `CrediYa` model file

Answer (score 2):

This is showing that `Class 'CrediYa\CrediYa\Model\CrediYa'` is not exist in your module. Also you can check the class `namespace` whichever it used by `CrediYa`. so you can find & correct it.

Comment: How did you consult it?